# Despliegue de EAR en TomEE

Tags: java-ee, tomcat, tomee

Empezando a explorar TomEE, me surge la siguiente pregunta: para instalar un EAR segun lo que dice la documentacion, se debe subier el EAR a la carpeta "apps" y dice que hay que modificar  el tomee.xml para que la carpeta de deploy sea "apps". ¿pero cual es la ubicacion de esta carpeta? no la veo por ningun lado. ¿alguien me orienta? Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la [documentación oficial](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-directory-structure.html):

> `/webapps`       Works the same way as it does for Tomcat. Drop your
>   directories/wars in here!   Removed examples (Just because most of
>   people does not care)
>
> `/apps` (does not exist by default)   Can receive WARs of course, but
>   also JAR and EAR files. Optionally add your resources.xml file here.

El directorio `/webapps` funciona igual que el de Tomcat, puedes poner ahí un fichero **war** y se desplegará.

El directorio `/apps` no existe por defecto, pero puedes crearlo a la misma altura que el directorio `/webapps`. Admitirá ficheros **war**, **ear**, **jar** e incluso puedes poner tu `resources.xml` aquí.